# How to register a nil default value with NSUserDefaults

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I'm calling `registerDefaults` in my app's static initializer like so:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{
    StringKey: @"A Value"
    ,IntKey: @123
    //,NilDefaultKey: nil
}];
```

The key in question points to an `NSData` value, which I handle specially when not present. After setting it for the first time though, other calls to retrieve the value for that key still return nil, until I relaunch my app.

What is the correct way to register that the default value should be `nil`? I tried using `[NSNull null]`, but got the error `Attempt to insert non-property list object null for key NilDefaultKey`, so I know that's not it.

Should I create my own placeholder value and check for that instead of null? That seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Isn't the default default value nil? Why do you want to set it to nil when 'not present' returns nil?

Comment: @Willeke I'm having issues after setting the value - I keep getting nil until I restart, then I get back the updated value. I'm wondering if it had to do with the default not being set right.